# Meaning of: Identity added: .ssh/example_rsa ((null))

Tags: ssh

I SSH connected to a server using:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/example_rsa root@xxxxxxxxx
```

I got the following response:

```
Identity added: .ssh/example_rsa ((null))
```

I'd like to understand:

1. Added to what?
2. What does the `((null))` at the end mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/example_rsa root@xxxxxxxxx
```

never prints

```
Identity added: .ssh/example_rsa ((null))
```

---

It would get print if you have run:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/example_rsa
```

The null means **comment** from the identity file ([source](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh-add.c#L267)). Your private key can have stored comment to easier distinguish between various keys:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Identity added: %s (%s)\n", filename, comment);
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, as to "never prints...", I realized that I did what I describe in the question on a Mac, so perhaps, it's different in Ubuntu.